# How to extract values from array json column into multiple rows in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

How can I extract values from the json arrays in `ranges` column as multiple rows Postgresq?

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id INTEGER, 
  ranges jsonb
);

INSERT INTO test_table(id, ranges) VALUES
(1,'[{"End": 100, "Start": 1}, {"End": 1000, "Start": 101}]'),
(2,'[{"End": 2000, "Start": 1001}, {"End": 2002, "Start": 2001}]')
;
```

Expected result:

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 101 | 1000 |
| 1001 | 2000 |
| 2001 | 2002 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_to_recordset` function for this :

```
SELECT ranges."Start",
       ranges."End"
FROM   test_table,
       jsonb_to_recordset(test_table.ranges) AS ranges("End" int, "Start" int)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/22d62/10